# How to make a webservice and connect android application with it

Tags: java, android, sql-server, web-services

I made an android game. Now i want to store game score of each user in a database.

I am not getting how i can do it, but as far as my findings i need to create a web service for it, where all the functionality for fetching and storing of data.

My questions are:

1. How to make a web service for fetching and inserting data in DB
2. how to connect android application to this web service

web service should be in java.

Comment: Using drupal or something like that u have to create a CMS where in data is saved. after that u can post username and score using simple httppost.

Comment: Or, you may use a cloud-based stack like [stackmob](http://stackmob.com/) if you can.

Comment: Seshu Vinay : I dont knw how to work in druple, can u please suggest me some java solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many questions on connecting an `Android application` to a `web service`.
If you plan to implement your `webservice` in `Java` then I suggest you use the [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html).

**EDIT**

Java has two standards for web services: `JAX-WS` for `SOAP` web services and `JAX-RS` for `REST` web services. Each of these have several implementations. However, I would prefer using the `Spring` web services.

Also, try reading about `Spring` from over [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html).

Hope it helps

Cheers